# How Do I get INR symbol as shown in pic ,In pycharm using BeautifulSoup library?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm, html-parsing, element

[image]

my code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
request = requests.get("http://www.amazon.in/Yunique-Plus-YU4711-2GB-RAM-Black/dp/B01HMNHNP2")
content = request.content
soup= BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
element= soup.find("span",{"class": "a-color-price"})
print(element.text.strip())
```

How it should be modified to get printed:  (INR symbol) 6,199.00 instead of only:     6,199.00
?

Comment: `inr = element.find("span", {"class":"currencyINR"}).string`

Comment: Can u elaborate it ?